# Moving Camera on X axis glm::lookat()

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to make a 2D camera on OpenGl using the function glm::lookat(). The problem is that once everything is rendered, I can't move the camera. I'm only trying to move it on an horizontal way.

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(this->Width), static_cast<GLfloat>(this->Height), 0.0f, 0.1f, 500.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
```

Comment: The problem when I do that is that it just stops rendering the background for no reason, everything else is still just fine.

Comment: Since I have no idea how your background is rendered, I have no idea why that is happening. If you're using a screen-aligned quad, it's possible that it's just outside of the viewport once the camera moves. RenderDoc is your friend.

Comment: `Renderer->DrawSprite(ResourceManager::GetTexture("background"), glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec2(this->Width, this->Height));`  First parameter is texture, second position and third size. This backgorund is rendered from the renderer, with no Object class.

Comment: And `DrawSprite` does not use the view matrix?!

Comment: At this point, if this hasn't helped, post a Minimal, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. There's not enough information here to proceed otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I did what you said and now I have a static background, at least that's something, but what I needed is that when the player(object) moves to the right, the background and other stuff moves to the left so it seem like the player is moving inside a world space. Sorry to bother you and Thanks for everything, I'm somewhat new at OpenGL.

Comment: If you're using lookAt with a changing position, everything else should move. If it's not, something else is going on. Post a working example. (You'll find that, oftentimes, just generating the working example will help you discover the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);`

So, something like:

```
void Update()
{
  static glm::vec3 cameraPos(0,0,-1);

  cameraPos.x += 0.1f;

  ... etc
}
```

(Though, I'd suggest creating a Camera class, or at least storing the vec3 outside of this method, for anything beyond experimentation.) Everything else should work fine.

Typically, you'd also want to take into account the time difference between frames. There are many ways to measure this - whatever gl framework you're using probably provides a function for it - but you're *probably* running at 60Hz, so assume the time between frames is 16.6ms.  In which case, you might

```
float velocity = 10; // units per second
glm::vec3 cameraPos(0,0,-3);
float deltaT = 16.6e-3f; // 16 milliseconds

void Update()
{
  cameraPos.x += velocity * deltaT;
  glm::lookAt(cameraPos, .....);
}
```

You might run into a situation where everything renders the first frame, then disappears. In that case, drop the velocity to zero to make sure everything is working as it was before, then try some really small velocity values (like 0.001). It depends on how big your geometry is, distance from camera, and a bunch of other stuff. A camera Z of -3 is pretty small, might try backing it off some more while you're working this out.

Good luck!

Comment: That works but only for object that have their own Object Class, for object like the background which are explicitly rendered from the renderer they just disappear like this one: `Renderer->DrawSprite(ResourceManager::GetTexture("background"), glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec2(this->Width, this->Height));`  First parameter is texture, second position and third  size.

Comment: @Aether if you want the background to be static, use a different view matrix that doesn't use the camera's changing X.  Sketch this out  on a piece of paper. Your background is likely still there, just off screen. You could also move the background WAY out on the Z axis so you can see it moving away, or look at the vertex shader output in your favorite graphics debugger and see where it's going.